# setting ttl of google bigtable using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I was using aws dynamo db and used ttl property to delete record after some time 
but now i am moving to GCP,

In big table I can set expiration time for value hence I used Bigtable instead of Google Datastore

I know I can set that using Go CLI using command

> cbt setgcpolicy my-table cf1 maxage=1d

But I want to set it using gcloud cli or while creating using console or deployment manager

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this through `gcloud` or the Google Cloud Console. However, you can use the [cbt tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-overview), which is a component of the Cloud SDK (gcloud).

Also, [this Deployment Manager example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/01f0737a0dbffe3989863a64997c98a8d9cc2aab/examples/v2/bigtable/python/config.yaml#L18) should help with setting GC rules:

```yaml
tables:
  data:
    granularity: MILLIS
    columnFamilies:
      foo:
        gcRule:
          maxNumVersions: 2
      bar:
        gcRule:
          maxNumVersions: 2
```

Comment: I did not find property that specifies ttl in that link.
am I missing something?

Comment: You want the "gcRule" property

Comment: 'tables:
      data:
        granularity: MILLIS
        columnFamilies:
          foo:
            gcRule:
              maxNumVersions: 2'
  
will set ttl of foo to 2 milisecond , is that correct?

Comment: No, that keeps at most two versions of a column. I believe you can also say something like 'maxAge: 2d' for a time-based rule.

Answer (score 0):

The cbt tool is available as a [Cloud SDK component](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/go/cbt-overview). You  can check if it is already  installed by running following command:

```
gcloud components list
```

If it is not installed, you can run:

```
gcloud components update
gcloud components install cbt
```

After that, you should be able to run the same cbt command in your cloud shell.